# Reading and merging multiple excel files in R

Tags: excel, merge

This question and answers to this question already exist, but I find it difficult to understand the answers as I do not have so much experience using R.

I have multiple excel files that I would like to merge into one datasheet. Each excel file has the same number of columns, but different row lengths. I set the working directory to the file with all my excel files, and I tried using this code below:

```
   library(gdata)
   library(tools)
   filelist <- list.files(pattern = "*\\.xlsx$")
   files = lapply(filelist, read.xls, header=TRUE)
```

But I get the error:

> Error in findPerl(verbose = verbose) : 
>         perl executable not found. Use perl= argument to specify the correct path.
>       Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument

I don't understand this error. Is there a simple way to read and merge multiple excel files in R?

Comment: you should add `R` as a tag in your question

Comment: Corrected error formatting.